# Network stack crashed?

Tags: networking, network-programming

Our software includes a module to stream live video data to multiple clients. Most of time it works fine, but in some cases it seems to have caused some malfunction of windows network.

When it happens, the LAN connection status in network connections still says "connected", and the IP address is normal. But I cannot ping any other device in the network. The only way to fix it is to disable and then re-enable the network connection.

This problem seems to be OS-independent, it has happened on XP, Vista and Win7 machines.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Did my application crashed the network stack? or is it something else?

Comment: I would not call *XP, Vista and Win7* OS-independent ;)

Comment: This question is pretty hard to answer, and might be a hardware problem (like flaky switch). How often is "some cases"?

Answer (score 0):

More likely a fault with the networking switch unless you have a really bad NIC.

Cheapest route is to first replace the NIC, but ideally you should be able to reproduce the fault in a test harness so try with a direct crossover cable between two hosts first to rule out the networking infrastructure being at fault.

∴ Server Fault could be a better place to ask the question.